# Select Max() with GroupBy, using linq method syntax, EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, lambda, delegates

I have a bunch of classes with some data:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime bDate { get; set; }
    //One-to-one with course

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}


public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection <Student_Course> Student_Courses { get; set; }
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}


public class Grade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Mark { get; set; }
    //one-to-many with Student_Course

    public int Student_CourseId { get; set; }
    public Student_Course Student_Course { get; set; }
}

public class Student_Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //many-to-many with student
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    //many-to-many with course
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}

 public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime bDate { get; set; }
    //one-to-many with student_course
    public virtual ICollection <Student_Course> Student_Courses { get; set; }

}
```

Now i trying to write a query - for everyone teacher(name) needs to output his best student(name) by student mark, and the best mark, from class Grades, my code:

```
public IActionResult Task9()
    {
        var task9 = Db.Grades.GroupBy(gr => gr.Student_Course.Course.Teacher.Name).Select(x => new Task9
        {
            NameOfSt = x.Select(st => st.Student_Course.Student.Name).FirstOrDefault(),//Needs to correct this line
            NameOfTeac = x.Select(r => r.Student_Course.Course.Teacher.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
            BestMark = x.Max(gr => gr.Mark)


            //NameOfSt = Db.Students.FirstOrDefault(st => st.Id ==x.FirstOrDefault().Student_Course.StudentId).Name
        });
        return View(task9);
    }
```

So that code output correct teacher name and best mark on the course from students. But the student name is actually wrong. How can i fix that? Thanks for any help.

> Teac
>   BestMark
>   NameStud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use OrderByDescending by Mark before select student name:

```
var task9 = Db.Grades.GroupBy(gr => gr.Student_Course.Course.Teacher.Name).Select(x => new Task9
    {
        NameOfSt = x.OrderByDescending(st => st.Mark).Select(st => st.Student_Course.Student.Name).FirstOrDefault(),//Needs to correct this line
        NameOfTeac = x.Select(r => r.Student_Course.Course.Teacher.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
        BestMark = x.Max(gr => gr.Mark)        
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the `GroupBy` you need to use the value of the grouping (in this case `x`) to select the `Grade` object with the highest `Grade`. In the code below, I get the `bestGrade` object by ordering by the `Mark` in descending order and then taking the first entry and then I take the student, name and best mark from that object:

```
public IActionResult Task9()
{
    var task9 = Db.Grades.GroupBy(gr => gr.Student_Course.Course.Teacher.Name).Select(x =>
    {
        var bestGrade = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Mark).First();
        return new Task9
        {
            NameOfSt = bestGrade.Student_Course.Student.Name,//Needs to correct this line
            NameOfTeac = bestGrade.Student_Course.Course.Teacher.Name,
            BestMark = bestGrade.Mark
        };
    });

    return View(task9);
}
```